# Bott and Tu compact cohomology of the circle "differential forms in Algebraic Topology"

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

On page 27 of that book, it is claimed that the inclusion map $\delta$ which maps a form from the non-empty intersection of two open covers of the circle to the disjoint union of those covers has a one dimensional kernel:

$$ \delta : H_c^1 (U\cap V) \rightarrow  H_c^1 (U  \sqcup V) $$
$$ w= (w_1  , w_2) \rightarrow (-(j_U)_* w ,  (j_V)_* w)$$

where  inclusion simply extends the form by zero outside the intersection of U and V. Clearly, $(-(j_U)_* w ,  (j_V)_* w)$ is zero only if w is zero. So Kernel of $\delta$ is not one dimensional. Mistake? note the $U\cap V$ is two disjoint "arcs".

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff  and? Both have to be zero to get zero. So the kernel is  just zero form. Not one dimensional.

Comment: I assume you write elements of the source as pairs, taking the homology to be the product of the two components. But why are you writing elements of the image as pairs?

Comment: @Hurkyl: This is following Bott and Tu's notation, as they are identifying $H^1_c(U\sqcup V)$ with $H^1_c(U)\oplus H^1_c(V)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true that $(-(j_U)_* \omega ,  (j_V)_*\omega)=0$ iff $\omega=0$.  Note that $(j_U)_*\omega$ and $(j_V)_*\omega$ here are *cohomology classes* in $H^1_c(U)$ and $H^1_c(V)$, not just $1$-forms.  So we have to consider the possibility that they might be coboundaries.  A $1$-form on $U$ is a coboundary iff its integral is $0$, and similarly for $V$.  So $\ker(\delta)$ consists of exactly those $\omega$ such that $\int_{U\cap V}\omega=0$.  Since there is an isomorphism $H^1_c(U\cap V)\to \mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$ given by integration over each of the two components of $U\cap V$, $\ker(\delta)$ corresponds to the one-dimensional subspace $\{(x,-x):x\in\mathbb{R})\}\subset\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $(-(j_U)_* \omega ,  (j_V)_*\omega)=0\implies -(j_U)_* \omega=df,f\in\Omega^0_c(U)$ and similarly $(j_V)_* \omega=dg,g\in\Omega^0_c(V)$. $j_U^\star df=d(j_U^\star f),j_V^\star(dg)=d(j_v^\star g)$. So I get $d(j_U^\star f+j_V^\star g))=0$ but $f,g$ compactly supported, So $j_U^\star f+j_V^\star g)=0$. Why I do not get $\omega=d(j_U^\star f)$ and this implies that $\omega=0\in H^1$? What is wrong with my reasoning here?

Comment: You know $f$ and $g$ are compactly supported on $U$ and $V$, respectively.  That doesn't mean they are compactly supported when you restrict them to $U\cap V$.

Comment: I see. Is there a way I can proceed this way to deduce that $Ker(\delta)$ is 1 dimension in this manner?

Comment: Not really sure what you're looking for.  You're going to have to use some specific geometric facts about $U$, $V$, and $U\cap V$ somewhere, such as the characterization of coboundaries using integrals that I used in the answer.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.